# Using Timers in Cluster

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x, cluster-computing

I am using WebLogic 11g, Ejb3.0/Ejb3.1.

I am under **Cluster**.

I need to use **Timers** in order to invoke daily task.

How would I sync between the timers in the cluster? And avoid duplicate tasks?

Any tips, guidelines sample would be very welcome,

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: I'm wondering: Is there one single master database?

Comment: I will have couple of databases which I will connect to.

Answer (score 1):

have a look here:
[Clustered Timers](http://java.sys-con.com/node/43944)

I haven't implemented a solution like this myself, but right now we are using a plattform which uses a technique that resembles to what is described in the article.

Locking is done via the DB, on the same machine the tasks have a timeout and are synced/locked with a volatile bool that indicates that a job is running already

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [JAlphaNode](http://code.google.com/p/jalphanode/)

This is a standalone library, but it works under cluster.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate task and make the timer sych to multiple clusters,  you can  use EJB Timers and  you have to enable 'Timers are cluster aware' in your weblogic-ejb-jar.xml.

[See this](http://shaoxiongyang.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-use-ejb-3-timer-in-weblogic-10.html)

Answer (score 0):

We used Quartz and we haven't any issue on cluster environment

Comment: so is the task being executed only in one node ?